# if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.Equals("credit")) not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have grid view inside it I have debit/credit column and amount column in the credit and debit column if v_flag = d then return debit else return credit  html I wrote this :

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="debit/credit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label ID="debit" runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("v_flag").ToString() =="d" ) ? "debit": "credit" %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField  DataField="v_amount" 
                                HeaderText="المبلغ" ItemStyle-Font-Size="Small"/>
```

and it's work fine but when am trying to get the total of the credit only out side the gridview in text box and the total of the debit only out side the gridview in text box 
using this code :

```
   for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.Equals("credit"))
                {
                    sumCredit += Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
                    TxtCredit.Text = sumCredit.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    sumDebit += Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
                    TxtDebit.Text = sumDebit.ToString();
                }
            }
```

if (GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.Equals("credit")) not working it's always go directly to else statement

Comment: Are you sure `Cells[3].Text` is the cell you're expecting?  Have you looked at it in the debugger to see what values are there?

Comment: yes am sure that it's in cells[3].text , but in debugger the value is null

Comment: to me looks like you need to get label text and not the cells? does "debit" label contain the credit or debit text you are looking for?

Comment: It contains both debit and credit put I want the total of credit and the total of debit

Comment: @feby you should accept an answer if any of the answers work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.Equals("credit") it's like you are calling the innerText of a cell javascript Function.

So Change

```
GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text.Equals("credit")
```

by

```
var tempLabel= GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("debit") as Label;
    if(tempLabel.Text.Equals("credit"))
```

Comment: return an error cannot convert type table Cell to to textbox

Comment: Check my update. I made a mistake. You have to cast it as Label

Comment: no now it's return an error that cannot convert type table cell to label

Comment: I update the answer now, i test it in a porject and it works now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `FindControl` to get into the if-else

```
var debitTB = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("debit") as Label;
if (debitTB.Text.Equals("credit"))
```

Also `foreach` will make your code cleaner here.

```
foreach(var row in GridView1.Rows){
    var debitTB = row.FindControl("debit") as Label;
```

Comment: can you explain to me why did you declare debitTB  and then in if statment you use it instead of writing if (GridView1.Text.Equals("credit"))

Comment: for readability. you could also write `if (((Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("debit")).Text.Equals("credit"))` but it wont be very readable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; ++i)
        {
      Label lblcredit = GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("credit") as Label;
            if (lblcredit.Text == "credit")
            {
                sumCredit += Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
                TxtCredit.Text = sumCredit.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                sumDebit += Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text);
                TxtDebit.Text = sumDebit.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: it's return an error can't implicitly convert type label to bool

Comment: @feby i modified my answer please check now